# Varnish VCL simply replace client.ip for req.http.x-forwarded-for

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, x-forwarded-for

In my Varnish 2 setup I have a purging/banning block like so:

```
acl purge {
    "localhost";
    "x.x.x.x"/24;
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
            error 405 "Not allowed.";
        }
        return (lookup);
    }
    if (req.request == "BAN") {
        if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
            error 405 "Not allowed.";
        }
        ban("obj.http.x-host == " +req.http.host+" && obj.http.x-url ~ "+req.url);

        # Throw a synthetic page so the
        # request wont go to the backend.
        error 200 "Ban added";
    }
}
```

I'd expect that I could simply replace the `client.ip` in the if-statements for `req.http.x-forwarded-for`, but when I do the following compile error occurs:

```
Message from VCC-compiler:
Expected CSTR got 'purge'
(program line 944), at
('purging-banning.vcl' Line 16 Pos 41)
    if (!req.http.x-forwarded-for ~ purge) {

----------------------------------------#####----

Running VCC-compiler failed, exit 1
VCL compilation failed
```

I have been searching Google and StackOverflow, but I haven't found a good solution to my problem yet, or the reason why `req.http.x-forwarded-for` wouldn't be in the right place here.

Who can help?

Comment: Your example does not appear to match the error, you only seem to have "client.ip". However, just a note client.ip is an actual IP object, while req.http.x-forwarded-for is a string. purge is basically a list of IP mappings and is a special Varnish object

Comment: Thanks! Interesting note indeed :)

Answer (score 4):

Try using "ip" from the vmod_std. See: https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/vmod_std.generated.html#func-ip

Like so:

```
if (std.ip(req.http.x-forwarded-for, "0.0.0.0") !~ purge) {
    error 405 "Not allowed.";
}
```

This simply converts a string object to an IP object. Then, the IP object can be compared to the IP acl lists.

Comment: Thank you. I am currently unable to try this out (my original post was over a year ago), so I cannot mark your answer as "the answer".
However, I hope your answer can help others - or me - in the future.
If I'm able at one point to test this out, I will let you know.

Comment: doc was moved: https://varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/reference/vmod_std.generated.html#func-ip

Comment: This answer is good but not perfect because `X-Forwarded-For` can contain multiple IPs separated by coma. Apparently, `std.ip` fails in such situation so you need to use `regsub` to prepare the `X-Forwarded-For` so it contains only the first IP.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the 'rep' to comment, so I'm trying to affirm the answer using `std.ip`.  I have the identical situation, and using `std.ip` fixed it.  Remember to add `import std` in your default.vcl.

Also, in my case, nginx was forwarding to varnish, and X-Forwarded-For sometimes had 2 IPs in it, so I used X-Real-IP, which was set to `$remote_addr` in my nginx forwarding config.